# How do I load a font distributed with my application?

Tags: fonts

My image processing package has an 'annotate' utility that supports about a dozen fonts. It runs fine on my development system but, predictably, some fonts will not be installed on target systems. It is designed to run on any LINUX distribution.

I distribute needed fonts with my application, but I wish to spare users the hassle of installing the fonts. I am assuming no LINUX expertise on the part of my users, and I do not want them to have to be 'root' to do anything.

How can I make my application directly access the fonts distributed with it instead of forcing the user to embark on a confusing sysadmin font installation task?

Many thanks.

Imagtek

Clarification:

I'm targeting ALL Linux distributions. UBUNTU is a subset of all. Researching various LINUX distributions, there is a mishmash of approaches to font management. I cannot support each one individually. My app is designed to be installed under the user account, avoiding root access (until moving successful install to /opt) and accessing fonts from its distribution. Similarly, security concerns prevent running an installation script as root. Similarly, targeting ALL Linux distributions precludes becoming a client of any single Linux 'app store' and environment. Yes this is all politically incorrect and my apologies. Thanks.

Comment: Unless you're targeting Ubuntu specifically, you should ask on [unix.se].

Answer (score 0):

You don't want the users to have to use root? Installing softare usually requires root.

On Ubuntu (and I'd assume most debian-based distros) you can copy the fonts into a subdirectory of `/usr/share/fonts/truetype` (I assume they are TTF's) and update the font cache.

If you're creating a deb package, you can simply pack them so that they will be installed into, let's say `/usr/share/fonts/truetype/<softwarename>-fonts/`. In the `postinst` script, you can then run
`fc-cache -f -v`.

If you're simply publishing a installation script, `mkdir` the subdirectory, then `cp` the TTF's into it. Afterwards, call `fc-cache -f -v` to rebuild the font cache.